# Error: No match for 'operator<<' and 'operator>>'. Help please?

Tags: c++

Newbie here. Taking a Computer Science module in my college.
One of the exercises asked us to write a program that uses (int) data type.
I followed *all* of the codes written in my practical book, though I thought there was something fishy about it, and to prove I was right, after compiling, I got some errors.

Here's the code:

```
//Write a program that uses (int) data type.

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<cstdlib>
int main()
{
    int day, month, year;
    
    cout>> " Please enter the day of your birthday\n";
    cin<<day;
    
    cout>> " Please enter the month of your birthday"<<endl;
    cin<< month;
    
    cout>> " Please enter the year of your birthday"<< endl;
    cin<<year;
    
    cout<< "\nDay: "<< ", Month: " <<month<< ", Year: " <<year;
    
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I got are:

> 10 no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cout >> " Please enter the day of your birthday\n"'
>
> 11 no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cin << day'
>
> 13 no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cout >> " Please enter the month of your birthday"'
>
> 14 no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cin << month'
>
> 16 no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cout >> " Please enter the year of your birthday"'
>
> 17 no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cin << year'

I'm using Bloodshed C++ software, version 4.9.9.2.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to the answerd you received, you should also get rid of the "using namespace std", which you *never* want to put in front of an #include (and I don't even know if it's allowed in front of a *standard* #include like <cstdlib>). And you should certainly not get into the habit of using system("PAUSE"). You just execute the program from a command-line window or set up your IDE so that the standard program output goes to some special output window.

Answer (score 4):

`std::cout` is an output stream only, so it doesn't define an input stream operator `>>`. It defines `<<`, so you need

```
cout << "hello world";
```

and so on.

The inverse is true for `std::cin`, so you need

```
cin >> year;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to write:

```
cout << " Please enter the day of your birthday\n";
cin >> day;
```

As a crib for these operators you can think of their directions pointing to where the result should go.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
cout<<
cin>>
```